# what does Innovus dbGet command top.insts.cell.baseClass mean ? what are these values of top.insts.cell.baseClass mean?

Tags: database, routes, tcl, vlsi

dbGet command can be used to retrieve all the instances of the top block but exactly what are these values insts.cell.cellbaseClass?
how can I change them to point certain other level of hierarchy rather than with going to the top?
also what is the difference between get_db and dbGet?

trying to get info and understanding of the innovus built in commands.

Answer (score 1):

The values `insts.cell.cellbaseClass` refers to which class the insts    belongs to, that can be of class block/macro, memory or std cells.

if you want a particular hierarchy you can use this commands.

```
set hinst [dbGet [dbGet -p head.allCells.name name_of_hier].hInst]

dbGet $hinst.allInsts.name
```

or you can use the cui command

```
get_db [get_db modules -if {.name == name_of_hier } ] .hinsts.local_insts.name
```

dbGet commands used in legacy mode of innovus and get_db is ussed in    commun user interface mode of innovus